# Crystal heads-robots short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story about a museum curator who is put in charge of two old crystal heads. After a while it becomes clear that the heads are communicating to each other. They come from a different time and are robots?? Maybe?? They are husband and wife from long ago and they take up a conversation about why they are divorcing. It would seem the husband had a habit of undertaking long space travel thus abandoning his family. This was read probably in the 60's - maybe early 70's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reminiscent of the 1977 Brian Aldiss story "[Appearance of Life](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56819)".

A scholar researching in a huge museum finds a old "holocap", which is

> ... a hologrammed image of a real woman, with a facsimile of her brain
> implanted on a collapsed germanium-alloy core. It generates an
> appearance of life.

When activated, an animated, 3d, speaking representation of the woman's head appears within the holocap.

Later the scholar finds a holocap of the woman's husband, brings the two holocaps together, and activates them, so that they can have a conversation.

It turns out that they did get divorced, but also that the holocaps were created at different times (years apart), so the conversation turns out to be somewhat meaningless.

Comment: Fabulous! This is exactly it. Thank you. I love this site!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I wasn't sure, because it didn't exactly match your description. And welcome!